# libcurl with ssl in linux (curle_not_built_in error)

Tags: linux, curl, openssl, libcurl

curl_easy_setopt(Config->hHandle->curl, CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION, NULL))

is returning **CURLE_NOT_BUILT_IN** **error in linux**, where in Windows(Visual Studio) its working fine.

I built libcurl in linux with following commands:
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install openssl libssl-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev

but still getting same error even after building curl and libcurl with ssl

**EDIT** : Instead of gnutls i used openssl to build curl,

sudo apt-get install libcurl4-**openssl**-dev

problem solved

Comment: CURLOPT_SSL_CTX_FUNCTION only works with some SSL flavours (OpenSSL etc) but not with GnuTLS.

Comment: @n.m. that seems worthy of being an actual answer since that's the explanation for this...

Comment: @Daniel I'm not sure it applies to OP's actual situation. We don't know exactly what and how they have built.

Comment: I appreciate your pedantic level here! =)

Comment: if i type curl --version then it shows---- curl 7.47.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.47.0 GnuTLS/3.4.10 zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.32 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IDN IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets